# Concatenating two matrices together in Matlab

Tags: matlab

In Matlab, I have two matrices a(1x20) and b(1x20). I want to merge or concatenating them as a one matrix c(1x20). For example if

```
a=[1 3 2 0]
b=[0 1 2 2]
```

then

```
c=[4 13 10 2]
```

To explain that

```
a(1,1) = 01%// as a Most significant  bits
b(1,1) = 00%// as a least significant bits
```

so the result is

```
c(1,1)= 0100
```

Comment: Have you tried anything on your own? For example using `bitshift`?

Comment: So can matrix a have a value greater than 3, or is it restricted to two bits. Look at 4*a+b.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concatenation_(mathematics) is this the same mathematical computation you are doing with the bithsifting?

Comment: @ Daniel I try this code x=fi(a,0,2,0);
        y=fi(b,0,2,0);
        z = bitconcat(x,y);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formal way to do it is to use a [`bitshift`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bitshift.html):

```
wordSize = 8 %Size of your word, this is for your case

c = bitshift(a, wordSize/2) + b
```

you can also do some nice printing to check:

```
for i = 1:length(a)
    fprintf("%d: Part A: %08s \tPart B: %08s \tPart C: %08s\n", i, a[i], b[i], c[i])
```

*Warning, code not tested*

Comment: Dear Ben, Thanks for your answer, but I put the word size= 4 and the code works. Many thanks